# Issues with OnResume OnStop to change activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I was just trying to get to know well how to change activities and i made a simple example and yet nothing.
The thing is, i dont know how to go back to the main activity after changing to the second activity.

here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
private String DEBUG_TAG1 = "tag";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
      pauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {

       if (v.getId() == R.id.pause_button)
       {
           Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"pause");
           Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
           Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"intent created");
           i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(i);


       }


   }

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();  
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"on stop");

}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"on resume");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

here is SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
private String DEBUG_TAG2 = "tag";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Button pauseButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button2);
    pauseButton2.setOnClickListener(this); 

   }  
@Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {

       if(v.getId() == R.id.pause_button2)
       {
           //here i have to get back to the MainActivity

       }

   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and here are the XML files:

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="net.iversoncru.changeact.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause_button"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:text="||"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and activity_second.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="net.iversoncru.changeact.SecondActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause_button2"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:text="||"
    android:textColor="#aa0000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

can anyone tell me how?

I noticed that, when SecondActivity starts, OnStop() is called on MainActivity.
How do i use OnResume()?

Also i read that maybe i have to save the state of MainActivity to be able to be back to it...

Im a little bit lost.

Comment: on resume when you take activity back from background than on resume is called if you press back btn from second activity than frirst activity's onRestart method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {

       if(v.getId() == R.id.pause_button2)
       {
           //here i have to get back to the MainActivity
           finish();
       }

   }
```

when you switch to the next activity OS pushes current activity on the stack and brings forward the requested activity.

finish() method from activity class will announce to the system that you are done with your work in current activity and restore my previous activity on the stack.

Comment: thanks!! i think this finish() is perfect for this situation!, i dont really have to save states or whatever.
thanksssss, very useful